# Modifying SharePoint alerts to reduce the details in the email

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, alert

I'm finally getting my organization to use Alerts.  Which is great.  We are using SharePoint online. I send each team member a daily summary at 7:00 am.
The following are the settings:
Change type: All Changes
Send Alerts for These Changes: Anything Changes
When to Send Alerts: Daily Summary 7:00 am

From the screen shot below, you can see one team member has been working on a file, and every time the file saves, the alert records it, and if they've been working on the file all day, there are several lines for each file.  The team members have to scroll a long way down in the email to see all the files that have been modified.

Is there a way for information to be displaying with less information so that you don't have to scroll down in your email so much?
[image]

Comment: you have selected the option "Anythings changes" and your user keep on changing the files so it records and send as alert summary. I am not aware anything we can change in Alerts. may be instead of alert you should built some kind of workflow which will tell you the what are the files modified today in current Document Library or may MS flow will do.

Comment: Thanks @vinitkumar - I assumed the default view was the only option.  I was trying to avoid a workflow and use base OOTB SharePoint.